# Grails - save() failing with MissingMethodExcepition in integration test

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm learning groovy / grails, and writing my first integration test.

It's currently failing with:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
>   signature of method:
>   com.mangofactory.scurry.User.save() is
>   applicable for argument types: ()
>   values: []

My test isn't doing anything fancy:

```
class UserEventControllerTests extends ControllerUnitTestCase {
    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    protected void tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    void testAddingAUser()
    {
        def user = new User(emailAddress: "martypitt@test.com")
        user.save()
    }
}
```

Saving the entity works fine when I do it through the scaffolded pages provided by grails.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be an integration tests it shouldn't extend one of the unit test base classes, so change it to

```
class UserEventControllerTests extends GroovyTestCase {
...
}
```

and make sure it's in test/integration, not test/unit.

But it looks like you want to test a controller (it's called UserEventControllerTests) which should extend `ControllerUnitTestCase`. If that's the case then you should be doing unit tests, but mocking the domain layer (using `mockDomain` and others) since you want to focus on controller logic, not persistence. Test domain classes in proper integration tests using a database.

This is all described in chapter 10 of the docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/